# Reverse the direction of applying colours to sibilings

Tags: css

```css
input:checked ~ label {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>black</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>green</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>yellow</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>red</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>blue</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>gray</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>azure</label>
<input type='radio' name='color'>
<label>white</label>
```

How can I reverse the direction of colouring the `labels` with the `color: red`, Right now, When I click on `black` everything gets the `color: red`, But I want the reverse, So When I click on `white` everything gets the `color: red`

Comment: You can use flexbox to reorder visually your content (ie `flex-direction: reverse;`), but you'll also need to reverse the order of your markup as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider flexbox and reverse order like this:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

input:checked~label {
  color: red;
}

input:first-child {
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>white</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>azure</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>gray</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>blue</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>red</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>yellow</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>green</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>black</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Nearly the same code as mine, but submitted moments before. Great minds I guess! It looks as though he wanted to have the radio button before the colour label, though.

Comment: @adpro well, we are not obliged to provide the exact code needed :) the important part is to provide the idea of doing it, then he can simply adjust it ;)

Comment: True. If I left it that part out, and my link to Flexbox documentation, I likely would have been the first to submit and get that check then. Lesson learned I guess '-)

Comment: @adpro i don't agree ... it's not a question of being fast or a race to earn the mark ... we provide our solution and the OP choose the one we want but these solutions will remain useful for future comer, so the link in your answer is still useful even if it's not the accepted answer

Comment: This situation is quite different since both answers are very similar. But, far too often an answer is accepted that isn't the best answer, or isn't the most complete answer, but was answered quickest. Again, this isn't the case here since the difference is so small and the answers are essentially the same. In larger cases it's just annoying when you type out a nice complete answer and it isn't accepted, because someone else rushed and got theirs submitted first, then edited it to include more detail. I guess stuff like that can't really be avoided, though.

Comment: @adpro this is because you are thinking like them ;) and you are running against the accepted mark ... check well known answers to see that secondary answer and getting more upvotes than the accepted ones ... so being fast will only make us win the little green mark, but if we take our time to provide detailed answer we will win much more as we will be upvoted in the futur ... simply don't think about Rep and think about good quality and you will see the result in the future ;)

Comment: Yes, that is good advice for sure. I have not rushed anything yet for this reason. I don't think I would have it in me to do that, and I'm sure there end up being some down-votes for rushed answers. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) helps with things like this.

There are other ways, but here's one.

```css
input:checked ~ label {
    color: red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>white</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>azure</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>gray</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>blue</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>red</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>yellow</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>green</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
  <label>black</label>
  <input type='radio' name='color'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add float:right in input and label
eg. input,label{ float: right;}